# Overflow visible not working properly combined with auto overflow property

Tags: html, css, overflow

This might be a old question. I referred many link's in stack overflow where solution for the same has been posted. But i can't find anything useful to me. I have read that `overflow:visible` acts as auto when combined with auto properties. I understand those, But I need a solution to overcome this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have set of tabs in my page in which i will add an active class to tabs `onclick`. That's a JS work around. Need not worry about that i can work it. My problem is, that `overflow-y:visible` seems to hide the active state top border. I need it to be visible and also to ensure my X-axis should have a scroll. Given my code below. Class to be noted down is `tabs.activeTab:before`

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="tabs activeTab">
    Tab1
</div>
 <div class="tabs">
    Tab2
</div>
<div class="tabs">
    Tab3
</div>
<div class="tabs">
    Tab4
</div>
<div class="tabs">
    Tab4
</div>
```

```
.outer{
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background:#00adfc;
    overflow-y:visible;
     border:1px solid #00adfc;
}
.tabs{
  position:relative;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  border-right:1px solid #fff
}
.tabs.activeTab:before{
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:-3px;
  border-top:3px solid #fff;
}
```

Also refer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rtunypnj/)

want something like this[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: If i get you right you want to have the `border-top:3px solid #fff;` be visible on the active tab, correct? If so just remove the `top: -3px;` with `top: 0px` otherwhise it will be out of the visible range

Comment: s it should not be hidden. But overflow-x auto hides it.

Comment: try out https://jsfiddle.net/ns3hd4ek/ is this what you want it to be?

Comment: I have a attached a pic..Refer it